# ForceContext Queries method twice?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm doing a per minute script, to output the xml that a server will read. Ive logged url requests and for some reason, calling this url once, calls it twice!

It seems that as soon as Zend notices the  tag, it re-renders the method.

```
echo $this->minutes; exit; -method successfully called once
echo '< html >'.$this->minutes.'< / html >';exit; -method successfully called once
echo '< rss >'.$this->minutes.'< / rss >';exit; -method called twice!
```

Even if you put < rss > inside the view template, or in the method, zend somehow captures it and re-calls the method! >/